# use mySQL process id to locate PHP script that issued query

Tags: php, mysql

We are trying to locate a PHP script that is assembling a query and causing havoc.  So far we have not succeeded in using grep to locate the script.

Is it possible to use the mySQL pids from `show processlist` to locate the PHP script issuing the query?

Comment: If PHP connects to your MySQL server over TCP, then you can reconcile the `Host` info with the pid that opened that port (although I'm not convinced that will get you any closer to identifying the underlying PHP script); but this method won't work if the connection is over a UNIX socket.  You could have PHP write the script + MySQL connection ID to a logfile somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think so. Much would depend on actual architecture and topology.

Maybe - this, too, might be hugely disruptive, depending on the context - you could attempt to override the mysql_query function (or whatever wrapper is in use among the various scripts) so as to recognize the misbehaving/malicious query and log all relevant information.

See: https://www.php.net/runkit_function_redefine

Since the logging would take place from "inside" the havoc-wreaking script, much more information would be available.

Another possibility could be to filter MySQL queries and induce some recognizable behaviour in the script, like waiting for a long time or throwing an error. This might be doable through MySQL Proxy: https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy

Assuming the script is malicious, inability to locate it might point to some kind of encryption - and usually such scripts make heavy use of eval(), base64_decode and sometimes gzuncompress(). Looking for these functions might be more productive than searching for the query fragments.

A useful hack, not very useful now, could be to "decorate" queries with revealing comments, such as, "SELECT ... WHERE ...; -- 012345": the "-- 012345" part would be ignored by MySQL, but could be easily logged, and grepping "-- 012345" would quickly find the target.